# Reload Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, fragment

I am just curious, as I have set up Fragment tabs in a FragmentActivity, how to reload a fragment either from the FragmentActivity, or from the Fragment itself, to just purge and reload that tab. I essentially need the same thing that happens when I reselect the tab to happen, when it replaces the fragment. Is there a simple way to do this and reload the fragment ?

Comment: For what reason do you need to reload a fragment?

Comment: need to reload/ refresh really it's view because I need to update something that is populated from a server and changes depending on the number it receives. It currently works as if I select another tab and reselect the tab I have. But since the activity doesn't receive it in time at load it doesn't know what it is quick enough.

Comment: see my answer and tell me if it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a method that begins a FragmentTransaction, detaches the fragment, and commits. Then begin a new FragmentTransaction which attachs the fragment and commits. This should destroy the view hierarchy, create it again, attach it to the UI and display it. Whenever you need the fragment refreshed, jsut call this method.

Comment: I don't think this is working because it blanks out the screen giving not really any error until it runs out of memory replacing the fragment, but I think this might be because it still didn't receive the value I needed it too. I'm just not sure why it wouldn't though could you give me some example code for this to see if I did it properly.

Comment: @kev2316 when the number is received, that is when you should call the above method.

Comment: Actually yeah it worked thank you, I had an error were it wasn't getting it and just was "refreshing" the fragment to often. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
fm=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
{
fm.beginTransaction().replace(Containername, new CurrentFragmentname, CurrentFragment.class.getName()).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the answer is actually pretty simple,
**getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();**