# Re-loading Fragment from inside itself

Tags: android, android-fragments, refresh

I have been trying to figure out how I would be able to refresh my Fragment from a menu button that is defined inside the Fragment.

I have looked at [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097225/reload-fragment) but I was hoping for a more detailed example on how I would be able to achieve this.

Any help or Guidance would be appreciated, thanks.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.clear_cache:
        mImageFetcher.clearCache();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.clear_cache_complete_toast,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    case R.id.random:

        //Reload the fragment from here

        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.gridView, new Fragment3())
        .commit();


        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

XML:

```
        <activity
        android:name="com.stackoverflow.question.ImageGridActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        </activity>
```

Crashes with:

```
12-04 09:48:27.636: E/AndroidRuntime(20461): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 09:48:27.636: E/AndroidRuntime(20461): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
12-04 09:48:27.636: E/AndroidRuntime(20461):    at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:451)
12-04 09:48:27.636: E/AndroidRuntime(20461):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
12-04 09:48:27.636: E/AndroidRuntime(20461):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
12-04 09:48:27.636: E/AndroidRuntime(20461):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
12-04 09:48:27.636: E/AndroidRuntime(20461):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
12-04 09:48:27.636: E/AndroidRuntime(20461):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
12-04 09:48:27.636: E/AndroidRuntime(20461):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-04 09:48:27.636: E/AndroidRuntime(20461):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-04 09:48:27.636: E/AndroidRuntime(20461):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
12-04 09:48:27.636: E/AndroidRuntime(20461):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
 12-04 09:48:27.636: E/AndroidRuntime(20461):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 09:48:27.636: E/AndroidRuntime(20461):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-04 09:48:27.636: E/AndroidRuntime(20461):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
12-04 09:48:27.636: E/AndroidRuntime(20461):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
12-04 09:48:27.636: E/AndroidRuntime(20461):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When using @Matthew Mcveigh answer:

```
12-04 10:05:09.315: E/AndroidRuntime(21072): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 10:05:09.315: E/AndroidRuntime(21072): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-04 10:05:09.315: E/AndroidRuntime(21072):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:666)
12-04 10:05:09.315: E/AndroidRuntime(21072):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
12-04 10:05:09.315: E/AndroidRuntime(21072):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
12-04 10:05:09.315: E/AndroidRuntime(21072):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-04 10:05:09.315: E/AndroidRuntime(21072):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-04 10:05:09.315: E/AndroidRuntime(21072):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
12-04 10:05:09.315: E/AndroidRuntime(21072):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
12-04 10:05:09.315: E/AndroidRuntime(21072):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 10:05:09.315: E/AndroidRuntime(21072):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-04 10:05:09.315: E/AndroidRuntime(21072):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
12-04 10:05:09.315: E/AndroidRuntime(21072):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
12-04 10:05:09.315: E/AndroidRuntime(21072):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Looks like it may be a problem with the xml of the fragment's view, can you post that too please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside Fragment put these:

```
private Callbacks mCallbacks;


public interface Callbacks {
        //Callback for when button clicked.
        public void onButtonClicked();
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks
        mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;

}
```

In onOptionsItemSelected change to

```
case R.id.random:

mCallbacks.onButtonClicked();
break;
```

Make your FragmentActivity to implements YourFragment.Callbacks  :

```
public class YourActivityName extends FragmentActivity implements YourFragment.Callbacks
```

Inside the FragmentActivity containing the Fragment add this:

```
    @Override
    public void onButtonClicked() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.gridView, new Fragment3())
        .commit();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I get a crash. I have updated my answer with update.

Comment: @Jack Sorry that I provided a wrong method before. I have edited my answer. Remember to change "YourActivityName" to the real FragmentActivity name you have. Also change "YourFragment" to the real name.

Comment: I can't use "public class YourActivityName extends FragmentActivity implements YourFragment.Callbacks" because I have already got my Fragment set up as "public class Fragment3 extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {"

Comment: @Jack No, it is the declaration of the FragmentActivity containing your Fragment3. For example, you have a FragmentActivity -- "ImageGridActivity" , and the "Fragment3" contained by this "ImageGridActivity". Then you have something like this `public class ImageGridActivity extends FragmentActivity implements Fragment3.Callbacks`   to declare your FragmentActivity

Comment: Ok that makes sense now, I will give it a try =)

Comment: Glad to hear that!! I used to struggle a lot with the Fragment and FragmentActivity, so now I am really happy to be able to help someone.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done with 2 lines, just add them inside your refresh/reload button (Kotlin code)

```
try_again_button.setOnClickListener {
                val ft = fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
                ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit()
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to detach the fragment and attach it again. A one line code is enough :

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit();
```

Comment: You may want to explain why this code solves the problem.

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.