# How to apply night mode without reloading fragment?

Tags: android

I used light/night mode in my android project and I use a switch in a fragment to change mode. Well, It changes when I reload the app. But I wanna change mode without reloading the app. How can I do this???

- I wanna stay the current fragment when changed mode.

  ```
  aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
          if(b){
              AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
              aSwitch.setChecked(true);
              sh = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("darklight",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
              sh.putBoolean("is",true);
              sh.commit();
          }else{
              AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
              sh = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("darklight",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
              sh.putBoolean("is",false);
              sh.commit();
          }
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: You don't have to restart the app but you will have to restart that activity and fragment and to make the process seamless for users you would have to save and restore the state properly. https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/9i8eo7/how_are_you_doing_dark_modenight_theme_in_2018/

Comment: @NIKHILMAURYA I wanna stay into the current fragment when changed mode.

Comment: That's where the saving the current state part comes in. Basically you activity that is hosting this fragment will be reloaded and at that point of time you have to save this information that after the reload is complete you will get the savedInstanceState data about the fragment that was attached to it and try setup again.

Comment: by reloading fragment you can achieve it. you need to go through it's OncreateView in order to provide new changes in setTheme. you can reload by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357557/re-loading-fragment-from-inside-itself

Comment: if you are facing while reloading fragment then simple solution is restart that activity which is containing that fragment, at onCreate call this fragment , you need to manage this using flag(boolean) which is getting it's value in onCheckedChanged.

Answer (score 2):

You can do so easily by using the *AppCompatDelegate* command in Android

**To Set it to False**

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
```

**To Set it to True**

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
```

Additionally you can also use a switch button to apply modifying and switching between modes.

Answer (score 0):

Let's set a global variable for night mode switch in your Settings fragment. Then, let's set it when user toggles Night Mode:

```
var nightModeSwitched = false

class SettingsFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        nightModeButton.setOnClickListener {
            nightModeSwitched = true
            // Additional code to switch night mode on/off
        }
    }

}
```

Your parent/navigation activity will be reloaded following the changes on *AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode*. Then, let's redirect the user from your navigation activity to your Settings fragment, when night mode has been switched:

```
class NavigationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (nightModeSwitched) {
            loadFragment(SettingsFragment())
        }
    }

}
```